# Report - Reload Data when using multiple Schema

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I've created a report mixing multiple schema/cube.
One schema contains near realtime data that should be reloaded frequently while others changes on daily basis. 
If i set a refresh period in the general layout settings ALL the schema are going to be reloaded; this forces to redraw MDX filters and graphs not interested on the "RealTime schema" that has changed.

I'm trying to force a reload of the MDX query of specific graphs using javascript. Firing an event on the "Do Refresh Query" but i never see any GVI request for reloading data.

How to programmatically tell the report to reload ONLY a single schema or just not cache existing data and request always new on the server?

[image: Upper part of the report needs realtime data]

Answer (score 0):

The reporting does not force the server to reload a schema.

The "Refresh Period" (in the report) is defining a polling interval; i.e., every "Refresh Period" the report is asking the server about new data. In case new data is available then the report is updating each widget sending new requests.

In case of several schemas are using in the report, the polling request is based on the "default" schema.

As of icCube 6.8x, in case new data is available all widgets are refreshed. Preventing a widget to be refreshed is not supported (contact icCube support).

Hope that helps.